# Restricting 0 as first digit working fine in mac keyboard but in windows input field except 0 as first digit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to restrict 0 as first digit in input field. It works fine in macbook, but when user enter the amount in windows system the input field excepts the digit 0 and it is also not excepting the digit 9 as first digit, for eg: 9845 but it excepting like 8945. Below is the code.

I am just getting confused as where the bug is. It would be great if anyone can help me out with this:

JS CODE:

```
$("#stamp_amount").keydown(function (e) {
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
         // Allow: Ctrl+A, Command+A
        (e.keyCode == 65 && ( e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true ) ) || 
         // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
             return;
    }

    if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8) {
        // let it happen, don't do anything

    }
    else {
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((event.keyCode !==9) && (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 )) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }   
            else{

          if($.trim($(this).val()) =='')
        {
            if(event.keyCode == 48 || event.keyCode == 57 || event.keyCode == 96 || event.keyCode == 105){
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }
        }

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking what key was pressed check input value itself.

Regex `/^0|[^0-9.]/` means `starts with 0 or contains character other than numbers and .`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#inp').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0 || /^0|[^0-9.]/.test($(this).val())) {
      $('#valid').removeClass('valid');
    } else {
      $('#valid').addClass('valid');
    }
    
    // make input valid
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^0+|[^0-9.]+/, ''));
  });
})
```

```css
#valid:after {
  content: "No";
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#valid.valid:after {
  content: "Yes";
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inp" placeholder="51.54" />Eur
<br/>
<span id="valid"></span>
```

Comment: Justinas it's excepting alphabets I don't want that to happen

Comment: @PreetySingh So regex `[^0-9.]+` will match anything that is not number or dot and that way you filter for letters.

Comment: is there any other way to implement because this is not accurate according to the current scenario.

Comment: your answer was useful I did little bit modification with my code and included this line in my code: 
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^0+|[^0-9.]+/, ''));

and it worked like I wanted. Now I just have to give an error message if the user types 0 as first digit. Thank you so much :)